# Pass a variable from a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i need to display all values, so i used a foreach loop.
I need that when the user click on the button " READ " the value passed to `oldvisit.php` is the value of that row, i tried with SESSION but the value passed is the last of the Array.
Of course the values displayed in the page is the right value, but how can i take it and send to `oldvisit.php` ?
I cant use the form method, because these lines of code, are still inside a Form.
I cant find a solution from days!

```
<?php 
foreach($Visits as $x => $x_value) {
    $_SESSION['data'] = $x;
    echo "<li><center>". $x . " <input type='button' value='READ' onclick='window.location.href=\"oldvisit.php\" '></li>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps use `$_GET`? append `?row=$x` to `window.location.href=\"oldvisit.php\" ` and use `echo $_GET['row']` in *oldvisit.php*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code overwrites `$_SESSION['data']` on each loop and therefore `$_SESSION['data']` will always be set to the last loop value. I'm assuming the keys on `$Visits` (`$x` on your code) are the identifiers you want to use.

*index.php*

```
<?php
foreach($Visits as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<li>" . $key . " <input type='button' value='READ' onclick='window.location.href=\"oldvisit.php?id=".$key."\"'></li>";
}
?>
```

*oldvisit.php*

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id']; // Remember security (sql injection, etc...)
?>
```

This example uses the query string (everything after **?** in the url) to pass data between scripts. Paramerters in the query string can be accessed using the [reserved variable `$_GET[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).